# Write a Formula For a Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

So I have the sequence {13, 11, 9, 7,…} and I need to write a formula to find the nth term. Since it is decreasing by 2 each time, I figured it would be            an = an-1 -2, but I realized that you would still have to have the term before to solve for the nth. So how would I come up with a formula that does not need to have any other terms in the sequence besides the first?

Comment: $a_n=13-2n$, starting at $n=0$ ?

Comment: How were you able to figure that out so easily?

Comment: The $n$-th term of an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) has the general formula $a_n=\alpha n+\beta$ for some constants $\beta$ and $\alpha$. Specifically, $\alpha$ is the difference between two consecutive terms and $\beta=a_0$.

Comment: Okay thank you. But how about a geometric sequence? Such as {3, -6, 12, -24,…} Is there a general formula for a geometric sequence?

Comment: Yes.  Geometric follows the form $a_n = a_0\cdot r^n$ where $r$ is the ratio.  In that case $3\cdot (-2)^n$

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression).

Comment: There is a more general method to solving for closed forms, which for [linear recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) is well understood, but much more complicated than what you are probably ready for.

Comment: So I just did the math, wouldn't the formula be to the power of n-1 instead of n?

Comment: That depends on whether you consider the first term to be $a_0$ or whether you consider the first term to be $a_1$.  Both are common in practice, but $a_0$ being the initial term is much more common.